# Can I use the trainer port on a DJI Phantom 2 controller for a buddy box connection?

Tags: dji-phantom, buddy-box

I am trying to teach my wife how to fly drones, and as I have an old DJI Phantom 2 with two controllers, I wanted to buddy box her on it.

I know there is a trainer port on both transmitters, but are they the same function as on Spektrum or other transmitters? And, if so, which switch changes it between master and slave?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve done some digging to try to find you an answer.

As far as I can tell, the trainer port on the back is only for use in a simulator as evidenced in links: [1](https://phantompilots.com/threads/trainer-port.30206/), [2](https://youtu.be/QlRvbxTWYaI), [3](https://forum.dji.com/thread-2526-1-1.html).

According the links [4](https://www.dronevibes.com/forums/threads/buddy-box-a-phantom-student-to-learn-people-some-confidence.27071/), [5](https://phantompilots.com/threads/setting-up-phantom-2-vision-with-a-buddy-box.15075/), there is no known way to get buddy-box functionality without modification. You could also install your own receiver and use a transmitter system that is compatible with buddy-box technology.

Comment: I also did a bit of research and came to the same conclusion.